What would be the time/approx.-complexity of making a special graph into hole-free?
When $G$ is $\{C_4, gem \}$-free, there is a constant approximation algorithm to make $G$ $\{C_{\geq 5}\}$-free, see chordal-distance-contant-approx, which gave a constant approximation algorithm for chordal/distance-hereditary vertex deletion.
Distance-hereditary graph is a super-class of chordal/distance-hereditary. I wonder to know whether there is a constant approximation for diatance-hereditary vertex deletion. And I want to know when $G$ is $\{house, gem, domino\}$-free, whether there is an approximation to make $G$ $\{C_{\geq 5}\}$-free?

Further more, I want to know, given a $\mathcal{H}$-free graph $G$, the time/approximation-complexity of making $G$ $\{C_{\geq 5}\}$-free?
In algorithmic graph theory, obtain a contant-ratio approximation for chordal vertex deletion is an open problem, where chordal is hole-free ($C_{\geq 4}$-free).
Very grateful for some useful references.
